# How should I structure my application in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm designing a PHP Application with code igniter framework and i have structured it in the form of an MVC however I'm confused in the sense of how I should create things. My current issue is that after the user logs in the session is stored and is accessed in the controller the model doesn't know anything about the current session so i find myself having to pass it the userID every time I want to use the model (IE update or get user information) this seems inefficient to have to keep doing this every time. I'm wondering if there is a better way or if i made a mistake in the way i organized my code.

Comment: Going off what you have said this seems absolutely fine. For the sake of keeping you code abstracted it's better to pass an id to a model to load it, however, without seeing a working example of your code I couldn't really say for definite.

Comment: I see this makes sense however it just seems dumb to me to pass in the userID every time i need to make a change or get some data to it (considering on each page I may need to do this several times). My goal in this project is efficiency and speed thats what drove my decisions in server software database and even framework (without compromising easiness to design to much).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example: you have a controller with a bunch of user methods.
you have already logged in the user in a separate controller and you are using a cookie and database session

create a constructor in your controller

```
public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model( 'users' );

        // return the $user object 
        if ( ! $this->user = $this->users->returnUserFromCookie() ) {
            redirect( '/login/', 'refresh' );       }

        // assign the id 
        else {  $this->userID = $this->user->id ; }


    } //
```

if a user object does not come back from the user model then we redirect to login.

otherwise $this->userID is now available to any method in the controller, any method you call in your models, and any of the views you call.

```
    function showHistory(){

     $history = $this->users->returnHistory($this->userID) ; 

  }
```

AND in this case since we also have the $this->user object we can pull other data from it in any method.

```
function sayHello(){

$data['greeting'] = 'Hello ' . $this->user->first . ' ' . $this->user->last ; 

}
```

we didn't have to pass $user or $this->user into sayHello() because it was already available. **and we don't have to test if $this->user is set** because that check was done in the constructor. if $this->user is not set, the controller is never used.

you can assign $this->user to $data. that makes it cleaner in your views.

in the controller method assign to data and pass $data to view

```
$data['user'] = $this->user ;
$this->load->view( 'history', $data );
```

now in your view you don't need $this-> because we have a $user object.

```
<?php echo 'Hello ' . $user->first . ' ' . $user->last ; ?>
```

========= edit

> Thank you for your response, How do you access $user in the model?

the exact same as the controller examples. $this->user->id , etc

> Like how does the model know what user to do the database operation on
>   when you call it.

its going be the user that you called (or returned) in the constructor. 
so if you called $this->user where the id = 100 , then that is what will be available to the models.

Comment: Thank you for your response, How do you access $user in the model? Like how does the model know what user to do the database operation on when you call it.

Comment: replied above in answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use helpers also which helps you lot.

Like MVC We can use helper function that can use any where.
You can create your own helpers also.

**Loading a helper file is quite simple using the following function:**

```
$this->load->helper('name');
```

Where name is the file name of the helper, without the .php file extension or the "helper" part.

**For example, to load the URL Helper file, which is named url_helper.php, you would do this:**

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

For more you can follow this link [Codeigniter](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, could you explain this further i'm not sure I understand.